# How to use off-line files for reverse geocoding

Tags: here-api

There is a way to turn your Lat and Long to address using https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json.

However, is it possible to use AUCN181F1WAU000AACVR.tar downloaded file to do it off-line?

If yes, is there any example/documentation?

We develop ASP.NET application.

Why do we need it:

We have a fleet (several thousand vehicles) and we get about 20K requests per seconds to our API from our vehicles. These requests have Lat and Long and we need to reverse them to human readable address. If we use your API - there will be about 20K requests per seconds.
We do not think, that it is a good idea. That is why we need that data offline to do reverse coding inside the system.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to bulk process locations:

**1. MultiReverseGeocode**

The ReverseGeocoder (RGC) offers a way to reverse geocode up to 100 locations at a time by posting them to a dedicated endpoint called "MultiReverseGeocode" (MRGC):

```
/multi-reversegeocode
```

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-multi-reverse-geocode.html for details.

**2. BatchGeocoder**

The BatchGeocoder is an asynchronous service to bulk process up to 1 million addresses or locations in a batch.

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/quick-start-batch-geocode.html for details.

But note that there is no performance SLA defined for batch jobs to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use above js code.
Make sure that js and geojson files are in the same folder.

```
// Load GeoJSON.
var promise = $.getJSON("reversegeocode.json"); //same as map.data.loadGeoJson();
    promise.then(function(data){
        cachedGeoJson = data; //save the geojson in case we want to update its values
                map.data.addGeoJson(cachedGeoJson,{idPropertyName:"id"});  
            });
```